# Coupling spin 3/2 fields with electromagnetism (causally)

Tags: electromagnetism, causality, interactions, supergravity

I am trying to read literature regarding the coupling of massive spin-$\frac{3}{2}$ fields with electromagnetism. Apparently, an elementary (i.e. not composite) massive spin-$\frac{3}{2}$ field can't be coupled to electromagnetism so easily. If we try the minimal coupling to achieve this, it turns out that some degrees of freedom can travel faster than light. (This breaks causality.) This is known as the [Velo-Zwanziger](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Velo-Zwanziger+problem) problem. So minimal coupling is out of question.

The next thing that we can try is non-minimal coupling, something like $\bar{\psi}_\mu F^{\mu\nu} \psi_\nu$. Such a coupling would typically have a dimensionful coupling constant and thus might not be renormalizable, but let's not worry about it. The question now is: can we make this kind of theory (i.e. non-minimally coupled to electromagnetism) consistent/causal somehow? Unfortunately, I am seeing two contradictory answers in literature about this.

1. In paper [1] (see it's abstract), the authors are saying that the causality problem persists even for non-minmal couplings.
2. But in paper [2] (see the first paragraph of the appendix), the authors are saying that propagation of spin-$\frac{3}{2}$ fields becomes causal after adding non-minimal coupling.

I must have misunderstood one (or perhaps both) of these statements. Can someone clarify it?

Also note that supergravity also provides a way to couple a spin-$\frac{3}{2}$ to electromagnetism. But this necessarily involves coupling with a graviton. I don't think my question concerns supergravity, but I have still added it as a tag to attract experts.

References:

[1] [S. Deser, A. Waldron, and V. Pascalutsa
Phys. Rev. D **62**, 105031 (2000).](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.62.105031)

[2] [Sergio Ferrara, Massimo Porrati, and Valentine L. Telegdi
Phys. Rev. D **46**, 3529 (1992).](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.46.3529)

Comment: Nonminimal coupling to the Rarita-Schwinger equation is something I have been looking at recently, and if I have time to work things out more carefully, I will write an answer.  However, here is my first impression:  I am pretty sure Deser, *et al*. are correct in their analysis.  In fact, I think I see where the argument in the appendix of the other paper breaks down.  I think—although I'm by no means certain—that projecting out transverse polarizations in their paper is where the error lies.  There is no reason to expect that acausal propagation will respect transversality of the field.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0112182 by Deser and Waldron refers to "a large (if somewhat confusing) higher spin lore", and comments on Ferrara et al

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised no one tried to get the bounty for this question...